# How to clear values of SearchManager after providing the results in Android?

Tags: android

Is there a way to clear the input values of the default search manager that is used in Android? 
I need to clear off the search query that is being typed in the editbox after the results have been displayed!

Comment: after the results have been displayed try editbox.setText("");

Comment: That would work. But was just thinking if there's a way to call the 'X' (Close) button that gets displayed onFocus of the SearchView's EditText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use `searchview.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                      closebtn.setfocus(true);

        }
    });`
```

Comment: Thanks! So eventually, doing this would hide the keyboard too? And will not regain the focus again?